# Converting kwd files into odts fails

Tags: kubuntu, convert

I'm trying to convert kwd files into odt using Kubuntu 11.10 but I'm getting this error:

```
$ koconverter llaves.kwd llaves.odt

koconverter(3712)/koffice (filter manager) KoFilterManager::filterAvailable: The library  ""  does not offer a check_ ""  function. 

Object::connect: No such signal KoFilterManager::sigProgress(int)
KFilterDev::open: device is already open 
koconverter(3712)/export-filter-lib ProcessAttributes: Unexpected attribute  "xmlns"  in  "document-info" ! 

KFilterDev::open: device is already open 
koconverter(3712): "*** The conversion failed! ***
```

Answer (score 0):

Try open Your `kwd` file in Abiword and save as `odt`.

Also try to use `kword` itself to save `kwd` as `odt`.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me, to convert `X.kwd` to `X.doc`. It must be run in a GUI terminal emulator (eg xterm) rather than a text terminal.

```
unzip  X.kwd  maindoc.xml
abiword  -t X.odt  maindoc.xml
```

I then change the page size and margins in LibreOffice. I go to Format > Page..., set the width to 8.5in and height to 11in, and set each margin to 2, which means 2 cm.